# PHP string comparison, removing spaces

Tags: php, regex, string

I am looping through two datasets and the string comparisons are working except for one row:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `field`  enum('P','W','M', 'G') 

ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `field`    enum('P','W','M','G')
```

I believe it is because of the space in between 'M', 'G' in the first string.  I want to remove this but still keep the spaces in the first part of the string.

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: What precisely are you comparing, SQL statements or string data? Also, are you working with MySQL? If so, to alter the table with respect to the colum of enum data, the correct syntax is: ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `field` `field` enum('P','W','M','G'). The space between the 'M' and 'G' in the OP code is irrelevant to MySQ correctly parsing this SQL statement..

Answer (score 1):

You can compress all sequences of multiple spaces to a single space:

```
if (preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $string1) == preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $string2))
```

However, this won't help if the two strings are:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `field`  enum('P','W','M', 'G') 
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `field`  enum('P', 'W', 'M', 'G')
```

These are equivalent in SQL because the space after comma is optional. If you want to be able to handle this, you'll need to write a more elaborate parser that understands SQL syntax.